# memory leak when removing objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I hope to store MYFileObj to NSMutableArray (fileArray) and display data on an UITavleView(tableview).

```
//----------------------------------MYFileObj
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MYFileObj :  NSObject  {

    NSString *fileName;

}

-(void) setFileName:(NSString *)s ;
-(NSString *) fileName ;


@end
```

the array I want to store data

```
NSMutableArray *fileArray;
```

I created new object and add to fileArray

```
MYFileObj *newobj=[[MYFileObj alloc] init ];
NSString *ss=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",path]  ;
[newobj setFileName:ss];
[ss release];
[fileArray addObject:newobj];
[newobj release];

[atableview reloadData];
```

After the first time relaodData and do something, I want to reload fileArray and redraw atableview.

```
//code to remove all object in atableview
if([fileArray count]>0)
{  
   [fileArray removeAllObjects];
   [atableview reloadData];
}
```

I notice that there are memory leak.
I hope to know the method "removeAllObjects" removes only MYFileObj themselves or also removes MYFileObj's member property "fileName"?

Thanks

interdev

Comment: Please use declared properties. The getter and setter can be created automatically with `@property(copy,nonatomic) NSString* fileName;` in the interface and `@synthesize fileName;` in the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice is to use retain/release in the setter. This way you avoid unnecessary object creation/copy:

```
- (void)setFileName:(NSString *)s {
    [s retain]; // <- Retain new value
    [fileName release]; // <- Release old value
    fileName = s;
}

- (NSString *)fileName {
    return fileName;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [fileName release]; // <- Release the instance
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Wrong setter. `[obj setFileName:[obj fileName]]` will crash your app.

Comment: Fixed the setter (I hope). Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You do not state where you have detected the memory leak, but I'll assume from the posted code that you are not releasing the fileName in MyFileObj's dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

it depends how you implemented `setFileName` and `dealloc` in your `MyFileObj` class. Do you send a `release` message to `fileName` in `dealloc` ? Do you send it a `retain` in your setter ?